# Why do i get an error on a line that does not exist? [nasm]

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I'm trying to make an operating system and I use NASM as my assembler.
and I get the following error: `DiskRead.asm:25: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand` even if that line doesn't exist.
This is the code for DiskRead.asm:

```
ReadDisk:
    mov bx, PROGRAM_SPACE
    mov al, 4
    mov dl, [BOOT_DISK]
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov cl 0x02
```

Comment: I get the error on line 10, where you're missing a comma in `mov cl 0x02`.

Comment: Did you `%include` this into another file?  If so, that's a known bug in NASM's line numbering for included files.  Since this isn't a [mcve] of the error (as @NateEldredge said with this file alone NASM pinpoints the right line), I'm closing the question.  As a duplicate of the most likely explanation for wrong line numbers.  If that's not it, edit this to be a [mcve] that can be copy/pasted to reproduce your output, and say what NASM version you have.